# jQuery works immediately in Chrome but requires page refresh in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox

I'm using Rails 4.1.5 and jQuery 1.10.2. I have three js files with code in them, and they all works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But to get the jQuery to work in Firefox, I must refresh the page once; visiting a page without refreshing it yields a jQuery-less page.

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require parsley
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

_application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
<!-- Allow mobile scrolling. -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><%= full_site_title %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
  "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application",
  "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= favicon_link_tag %>
  </head>
...
```

custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

// Resize content-body div to fill the vertical space between the header
// and footer.
var resizeContentBody = function(event) {
    var content_body_height = $(window).height() -
    ($("header").outerHeight() + $("footer").outerHeight());
    $("#content-body").css("min-height", content_body_height + "px");
};

resizeContentBody();
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    resizeContentBody();
});
});
```

quarters.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00',
    useSeconds: false,
    useCurrent: false,
    minuteStepping: 15,
    language: 'en'
});

// Only the new form has a div with this class, so we check whether the
// class exists before grabbing the data. Otherwise, we'd get an error.
if ($('.deadlines_class').length) {
    deadlines = $('.deadlines_class').data('deadlines');
    $('#quarter_start_date').val(deadlines["start"]);
    $('#quarter_project_proposal_deadline').val(deadlines["proposal"]);
    $('#quarter_student_submission_deadline').val(deadlines["submission"]);
    $('#quarter_advisor_decision_deadline').val(deadlines["decision"]);
    $('#quarter_admin_publish_deadline').val(deadlines["admin"]);
    $('#quarter_end_date').val(deadlines["end"]);
};

$('#quarter-form-tooltip').tooltip({
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover'
});

});
```

evaluations.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){

function checkRadio(event) {
    if ($('#new-eval-question #_question_type').val() == 'Radio button') {
    $('#new-eval-question #radio-button-group').show();
    } else {
    $('#new-eval-question #radio-button-group').hide();
    };
};

checkRadio();
$('#new-eval-question #_question_type').on('change', checkRadio);

var rbDiv = $('#new-eval-question #radio-option-group');
var i = $('#new-eval-question #radio-button-group input').size();
$('#new-eval-question #add-option-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    i++;
    $('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="radio_button_options[' + i + ']">Radio button option ' + i + '</label><div class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control" id="radio_button_options[' + i + ']" name="radio_button_options[' + i + ']" type="text" data-parsley-required="true"></div><a href="#" class="col-sm-1 remove-radio-input" id="remove-radio-input[' + i +']">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(rbDiv);
    return false;
});

$('#new-eval-question').on('click', 'a.remove-radio-input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('id').
                  match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1], 10) + 1;
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    i--;
    var lastIndex = parseInt(
    $('#new-eval-question #radio-button-group input').last().
        attr('id').match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1], 10);
    for (var j = firstIndex; j <= lastIndex; j++) {
    var thisFormGroup =
        $('#new-eval-question div:contains("Radio button option '
          + j + '")').closest('.form-group');
    var replacement = (j-1);
    thisFormGroup.find('label').
        prop('for', 'radio_button_options[' + replacement + ']');
    thisFormGroup.find('input').
        prop('id', 'radio_button_options[' + replacement + ']');
    thisFormGroup.find('input').
        prop('name', 'radio_button_options[' + replacement + ']');
    thisFormGroup.find('a').
        prop('id', 'remove-radio-input[' + replacement + ']');
    thisFormGroup.find('label').
        text("Radio button option " + replacement);
    };
    return false;
});

/****************************************************************/

// Client-side validation

// Use Parsley to validate edit evaluation template forms.
window.ParsleyValidator.addMessage('en', 'required',
                   'This field is required.');

$('#new-eval-question form').parsley({ excluded: ':hidden' });
$('#edit-q-modal form').parsley({ excluded: ':hidden' });

/****************************************************************/

// var ordering_group = $('.ordering-select');
// var position_changes = {};
// ordering_group.each(function(event) {
//  var dropdown          = $(this).find("select");
//  var question_num      = $(dropdown).attr("id").match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]
//  var selected_position = $("option:selected", dropdown).text();
//  position_changes[question_num] = selected_position;
// });
// console.log(position_changes);
// ordering_group.change(function(event) {
//  var dropdown     = $(this).find("select");
//  var new_position = $("option:selected", dropdown).text();
//  var old_position = $(dropdown).attr("id").match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1];
//  // old_position corresponds to question_num above.
//  $("select#\\_ordering\\[" + new_position + "\\]").
//      val(position_changes[old_position]);
//  position_changes[old_position] = new_position;
// });

});
```

quarters.js.coffee and evaluations.js.coffee also exist but include only comments.

**EDIT:** If I navigate to the relevant pages by typing the address in the address bar, the jQuery runs immediately. If I click on nav buttons on the site to get to the relevant pages, then I need to refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks has been known to cause this type of issue with jQuery. Try turning it off. This may also help in some cases: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: For the record, both options (removing Turbolinks, and installing the jquery.turbolinks gem) work. Turbolinks can be removed by following [these](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4) instructions.